# Filter json object with multiple form select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an json object like this:

```
{"age":"18","50000": "641","100000": "1011","150000": "1391","gender":"female"},
{"age":"18","50000": "642","100000": "1012","150000": "1392","gender":"male"},
{"age":"20","50000": "643","100000": "1013","150000": "1393","gender":"male"}
```

Im trying to build a small "calulator" for showing the price based on user-input:

```
<label for="gender">Gender</label>
  <select id="gender" name="gender">
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
  </select>


<label for="amount">Amount</label>
  <select id="amount" name="amount">
    <option value="50000">500 00</option>
    <option value="100000">1 00000</option>
    <option value="150000">1 50000</option>
  </select> 


<label for="age">Age</label>
<input id="age" name="age" type="text" />
```

This is the javascript I have tried, but I can't seem to understand how I do the filtering and showing the correct values from the form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //JSON object
    var obj = {"data":
     [
      {"age":"18","50000": "641","100000": "1011","150000": "1391","gender":"female"},
      {"age":"18","50000": "642","100000": "1012","150000": "1392","gender":"male"},
      {"age":"20","50000": "643","100000": "1013","150000": "1393","gender":"male"}
     ]

    };


    //Find the value when form is submitted
    $('#target').submit(function() {

        obj.data = jQuery.grep(obj.data, function(element, index){
          return element.age && element.gender && element.amount; // retain appropriate elements

        });    

        //Empty the div
        $('#price-result').empty();

        //Show the result in div
        $("#price-result").append("Age: element.age, Gender: element.gender, Amount: element.amount, Price: element.price-from-json");

        return false;//Stop page from reloading

    });


});
```

Anyone got any tips how I can solve this?

Comment: See the edit for what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no element.amount in the obj.data. Age and Gender are there.

I am iterating over the data object checking if any values match. I am assuming that these will be unique records otherwise amount will be overwritten.

SEE THIS [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E65Vm/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//JSON object
var obj = {"data":
 [
  {"age":"18","50000": "641","100000": "1011","150000": "1391","gender":"female"},
  {"age":"18","50000": "642","100000": "1012","150000": "1392","gender":"male"},
  {"age":"20","50000": "643","100000": "1013","150000": "1393","gender":"male"}
 ]

};


//Find the value when form is submitted
$('#calc').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = jQuery.grep(obj.data, function(element, index){
      return element.age && element.gender; // retain appropriate elements

    });    

    var selectedGender = $('#gender').val().toString().toLowerCase();
    var selectedAmount= $('#amount').val().toString().toLowerCase();
    var selectedAge = $('#age').val().toString().toLowerCase();

    var amount = "";

    $.each(data,function(k, v){

        if( data[k].age.toString().toLowerCase() == selectedAge &&  
            data[k].gender.toString().toLowerCase() == selectedGender &&
            data[k][selectedAmount] != undefined){

            amount = data[k][selectedAmount];


        }

    });


    //Empty the div
    $('#price-result').empty();

    //Show the result in div
    var displayText = "Age: " + selectedAge + ", Gender: " + selectedGender + ", Amount: " + amount + ", Price: element.price-from-json";

    $("#price-result").append(amount == "" ? "No Results" : displayText);

    return false;//Stop page from reloading

});


});
```

Comment: Yes, I know. Just had it in there to better explain what I am trying to achieve. I think maybe there should be some sort of if sentence to determine what the amount value is.